# going from one HTML file to another HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with my programming exercise and I need to go from one HTML file to another but it is not working for me.

`

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
function userSubmit(){
    var choice, output;
    choice = document.getElementById('colourMenu');

    if (choice === 'file:///Users/missminimegs/Documents/pinkpulldown.html'){
        window.location.href = "file:///Users/missminimegs/Documents/pinkpulldown.html";
    }
}


</script>
<style>

    body {
    background: rgb(204, 204, 255);
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    text-align: center; 
    }


</style>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: who is calling`userSubmit`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you probably want:

```
choice = document.getElementById('colourMenu').value;
```

...otherwise `choice` is a DOM element object, not a selection value from some menu.

Second, I can't tell because you either didn't post all of your HTML, or your HTML is very incomplete, but I doubt that one of the choice values is "file:///Users/missminimegs/Documents/pinkpulldown.html", it's probably just something like the word "pink", and that's all you should be comparing `choice` to in your `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `getElementById('colourMenu')` will return entire HTML element not the content so if you just want content inside of it use `document.getElementById('colourMenu').innerHTML;` and make sure you call userSubmit() function.